# Remove object from array object Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating array object like follows:

```
var numberOfSameDeficiency = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

                    var deficiencyId = result[i].Deficiency_Id;
                    var deficiencyName = result[i].DeficiencyName;

                    //check to see if this deficiency is already in the list of available selections
                    if ($("#drpDeficiency option[value='" + deficiencyId + "']").length == 0) {
                        var option = $('<option>');
                        option.attr('value', deficiencyId);
                        option.text(deficiencyName);

                        $select.append(option);
                    }
                    else {
                        Tests = {};
                        Tests.TestId = testId;
                        Tests.DeficiencyId = deficiencyId;
                        numberOfSameDeficiency.push(Tests);
                    }
                }
```

And I want to remove object on different function like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                console.log(numberOfSameDeficiency);
                var isFound = false;
                var deficiencyId = result[i].Deficiency_Id;

                if (numberOfSameDeficiency) {

                    numberOfSameDeficiency.forEach(function (entry) {
                       if (entry.DeficiencyId != deficiencyId) {
                           isFound = true;
                        **numberOfSameDeficiency.splice(entry, 1); // Generating Error (Remove all items from array object)** 
                           return;
                       }

                    });
                    // console.log("end if");
                }
                if (!isFound) {
                    $("#drpDeficiency option[value='" + deficiencyId + "']").remove();
                }

            }
```

So what line code should be there to remove particular object from array object.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
for( i=myArray.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    if( myArray[i].field == "money") myArray.splice(i,1);
}
```

This also works

```
myArray = [{name:"Alpesh", lines:"2,5,10"},
             {name:"Krunal", lines:"1,19,26,96"},
             {name:"Deep",lines:"3,9,62,36" }]
johnRemovedArray = myArray
               .filter(function (el) {
                        return el.name !== "Krunal";
                       });
```

Comment: I think this is right. In your code you are affecting the original list you are calling `forEach` on - this is not good. for loop doesn't care about the contents of the array, just length

Answer (score 0):

Create this prototype function:

```
Array.prototype.removeElement = function (el) {
    for(let i in this){
        if(this.hasOwnProperty(i))
            if(this[i] === el)
                this.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Then call:

```
let myArray = ['a','b','c','d'];
myArray.removeElement("c");
```

It also works with objects:

```
let myObj1 = {name: "Mike"},
    myObj2 = {name: "Jenny"},
    myArray = [myObj1, myObj2];

myArray.removeElement(myObj2);
```